# What does "once back in" mean in this context?

Tags: time-words

> The interior was to become the idealised landscape for the National
> Romantics in the 1830s, but in Porthan’s time it was rather the
> productive agricultural economy which was the exemplar, as was also
> evident in contemporary travel descriptions by foreign visitors to
> Finland. One of these was the Englishman Edward Daniel Clarke, who met
> Porthan in Åbo in January 1800 and was impressed by his fluency in
> Latin and his intimate knowledge of his homeland. When Clarke set out
> on his sleigh trip eastwards to St Petersburg some days later he saw
> exactly the scene Porthan must have described to him in advance,
> despite the snowy season. Well-tended churches and fields alternated
> with forests and frozen lakes, and **once back in** Helsinki Clarke had an
> unexpected opportunity to visit Sveaborg.
> (bolds by me)
>
> A history of finland by Henrik Meinander

This is a question about the order of events. You see auther user "once back in" in the text above.  Does it mean that: Edward Clarke wen to St. Petersburg and came back to Helsinki and visited Sveaborg?

Or does it mean: Clarke visited Sveaborg when he was once in Helsinki before he went to St. Petersburg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Once' here is used in the sense of 'as soon as, or from the moment when'

Clarke went to St Petersburg, [and returned] and once (when/as soon as he was) back in Helsinki he had an unexpected opportunity to visit Sveaborg.

Once the snake was dead, the danger was over.
Once I got in my house, out of the heavy rain, I could take my wet
clothes off.
Once I get my diploma, I will be able to get a good job.
Once my grandfather is dead, I will be rich.

> once
>
> conjunction
>
> as soon as, or from the moment when
>
> *Once I've found somewhere to live I'll send you my address.*
>
> *Remember that you won't be able to cancel the contract once you've signed.*

[Once (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/once)